# Train and test dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's the dataset I'm using:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import warnings
    
with warnings.catch_warnings():
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
data = load_boston()
X = data.data
y = data.target
```

First, I converted the target dat into a classification dataset according to the prompt:

**Step 1: Split the range of target values into three equal parts - low, mid, and high.**

```
y = list(y)
for i in range(len(y)):
    index = y.index(min(y))
    if i < len(y)/3:
        y[index] = 100
    elif i > len(y)/3 and i < 2*(len(y)/3):
        y[index] = 200
    else:
        y[index] = 300
```

**Step 2: Reassign the target values into into three categorical values 0, 1, and 2, representing low, mid and high range of values, respectively.**

```
def numerial(y):
    if y == 100:
        return 0
    elif y == 200:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2

y = map(numerial, y)
```

**Step 3: Split the dataset into 70% training set and 30% test set.**

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 99)
```

So, when I run step 3 i kept getting a error saying:

```
TypeError: Singleton array array(<map object at 0x7fac066a57c0>, dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

I wonder which of the steps that I did wrong to keep getting the error message. Any idea?

Comment: The `y` returned by `map(numerial, y)` isn't an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this problem with the following modification:

```
y = list(map(numerial, y))
```

But, you can simplify your code using `cut` function from `pandas`.

```
y = pd.cut(y, [0, len(y)/3, 2*len(y)/3, len(y)], labels=[0, 1, 2])
```

Or, even simpler:

```
pd.cut(y, bins=3, labels=False)
```